# Adjust width of video in Chrome to remove black bars

Tags: css, google-chrome, video, html5-video

Using VideoJS to embed video and black bars appear on the side of the movie in Google Chrome because of the height of the controller. This issue doesn't occur with other browsers.

Looking to hide the controller, except on rollover, or find a way to adjust the width/height. When I adjust the width or height via CSS it causes spacing issues in other browsers that hide the controller by default.

Screenshot:
[image]

HTML excerpt:

```
    <div id="movieLayer">

<div id="movie">
<video id="abacus_holiday_video" class="video-js vjs-holiday-skin" loop autoplay controls
  preload="auto" width="640" height="360" poster="my_video_poster.png"
  data-setup="{  }" style=" width: 640px; height:360px;">


<source src="abacus_holiday.mp4" type='video/mp4'>

</video></div>

</div>
```

CSS Excerpt:

```
#movieLayer {
    position: relative;
    width:  640px !important;
    height: 360px !important;
    margin: 80px auto 0px;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow:  5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#movie {
    position: relative;
    width:  640px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't related to the code or the video, but instead to the DivX plugin I had installed in Chrome. Disabling it solved this issue along with a few others.